# Complex numbers from two arrays with Real and Imaginary parts

Tags: list-manipulation, complex

I have two arrays, containing the real and imaginary parts of a list of complex numbers.

```
Re = {{Re_number1},{Re_number2},...}
Im = {Im_number1},{Im_number2},...}
```

I was wondering which is the smartest way to combine these two parts in a single array, containing complex numbers whose real and imaginary parts are taken from the two arrays `Re` and `Im`:

Complex = {{Re_number1 + i*Im_number1},...}

I guess there will be different ways to do that, maybe one thing to keep into account is that I will then need to make operations on these new complex numbers that I will create.

EDIT:

As @Belisarius suggested, I have tried with:

```
field [fullREAL_, fullIMAGINARY_] := 
 Complex @@@ (Transpose@{fullREAL, fullIMAGINARY});
    field[fullREAL, fullIMAGINARY] // MatrixForm
```

But it doesn't seem to work, although I suspect that's because I have made a syntax error...Can someone show me where? The arrays where I stored my rel and imaginary parts are created this way:

```
n = L = 8;
sigma = 3;
mu = 0.0;


leftREAL = 
  Table[{RandomVariate[
     NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]]}, {k, n/2}];
rightREAL = Reverse[leftREAL] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullREAL = Join[ {0.0}, Most[leftREAL], rightREAL] // MatrixForm

leftIMAGINARY = 
  Table[{RandomVariate[
     NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]]}, {k, n/2 - 1}];
rightIMAGINARY = -Reverse[leftIMAGINARY] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullIMAGINARY = 
 Join[ {0.0}, leftIMAGINARY, {0.0}, rightIMAGINARY] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: `Complex @@@ (Transpose@{re, im})`

Comment: Thanks @belisarius, I have edited my question, as I have tried to follow your instructions...but still I cannot make it!

Comment: I assume you have numeric values for `sigma`, `L` and `mu`. Remove the curly braces in the first arguments of `Table` and drop the postfix `//MatrixForm`. belisarius' solution require you to have `re={0,re1,re2,re3...}` while you have `re=MatrixForm[{0,{re1},{re2},...,{ren}}]`. Similar consideration apply to imaginary parts.

Comment: You've got undefined symbols `n`, `mu`, etc.  Then you probably need to ditch the `MatrixForm`.  Pretty much you never use it in an assignment.  It's for display purposes only.

Comment: I have included the values for sigma, L and mu

Comment: Even if I remove the curly braces and drop the postfix //MatrixForm I do not get any result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's working code with corrected syntax

```
n = L = 8;
sigma = 3;
mu = 0.0;

leftREAL = 
  Table[RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]], {k, n/2}];
rightREAL = Reverse[leftREAL] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullREAL = Join[{0.0}, Most[leftREAL], rightREAL]

leftIMAGINARY = 
  Table[RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]], {k, n/2 - 1}];
rightIMAGINARY = -Reverse[leftIMAGINARY] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullIMAGINARY = Join[{0.0}, leftIMAGINARY, {0.0}, rightIMAGINARY]

Complex @@@ (Transpose@{fullREAL, fullIMAGINARY})

(*{0., -0.00212203, -4.79203*10^-10, 3.36556*10^-22, -1.88384*10^-40, 
3.36556*10^-22, -4.79203*10^-10, -0.00212203}*)

(*{0., 0.00201095, 3.07046*10^-10, -9.41259*10^-23, 0., 
9.41259*10^-23, -3.07046*10^-10, -0.00201095}*)

(*{0. + 0. I, -0.00212203 + 0.00201095 I, -4.79203*10^-10 + 
3.07046*10^-10 I, 3.36556*10^-22 - 9.41259*10^-23 I, -1.88384*10^-40 + 0. I, 3.36556*10^-22 + 9.41259*10^-23 I, -4.79203*10^-10 - 3.07046*10^-10 I, -0.00212203 - 0.00201095 I}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why not do

```
Most[leftREAL] + I leftIMAGINARY
rightREAL + I rightIMAGINARY
```

These could then be put into a single array if desired.

Alternatively

```
Flatten[fullREAL + I fullIMAGINARY] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Note that I have preemptively removed `MatrixForm` from the "full..." assignments and only applied it at the end as it sometimes discombobulates functions along the way.